# How to turn on minimap in Emacs on startup?

Tags: emacs

I installed Emacs Minimap mode, but find it cubersome to manually turn it on by typing <kbd>M-x minimap-toggle</kbd> each time I start emacs.

Is there a way to put a command such as above to automatically do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minimap-mode` is a minor-mode, and the default behavior is to be enabled globally (for major modes defined by the variable `minimap-major-modes`) when using the most recent version -- i.e, version 1.2 -- http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/minimap.html

The following code should enable it globally (for major modes defined by the variable `minimap-major-modes`) when starting Emacs, by placing it in your `.emacs` file.

```
(minimap-mode 1)
```